# Append web-scraped data to same excelsheet

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, append, multiple-columns

I want to fetch a column from web using a for loop (date_range) and append the column to the same sheet, with each iteration, next to each other.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import openpyxl

range = pd.date_range(start='5/12/2020', end='5/21/2020')

for date in range:

df = pd.read_csv("ürl")

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Sample.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')

writer.book = openpyxl.load_workbook('Sample.xlsx')

writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in writer.book.worksheets)

read = pd.read_excel(r'Sample.xlsx')

writer.sheets.write(1, max_column+1, df)

writer.save()

date += delta
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data, and more detailed explanation of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I don't have sample data. 
What I am trying to achieve is for the code to run a loop through a specific period and append the results in the same worksheet i.e. rows have stock symbols and the code will run through each day to fetch prices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution 1

I'm not completely sure what you have still, but I've tried to come up with this as a starting point. It uses the Yahoo Finance API to simulate your stock prices. This defines two functions, one that takes in one company symbol and gets the current market price of that company, and one that generalizes this to a dataframe by applying it to all the values of a column of symbols.

```
from datetime import datetime

def get_market_price(symb):
    try:
        comp_info = yf.Ticker(symb)
        return comp_info.info['regularMarketPrice']
    except Exception:
        return np.nan

def fetch_today(df):
    today = datetime.today().date().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    df[today] = df['Companies'].apply(get_market_price)
    return df
```

Here is some sample data, and an application of above functions.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Companies': ['XOM', 'GE', 'MSFT', 'BP', 'C', 'PG']
})

df = fetch_today(df)

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
  Companies  2020-05-25
0       XOM         NaN
1        GE        6.48
2      MSFT      183.19
3        BP       22.98
4         C         NaN
5        PG      112.29
```

In this example, you should read in your data every day with `pd.read_csv`, apply `fetch_today`, and then save that new dataframe with `pd.to_csv`. Each time you run it on a new day, it appends a column with a title of the current date with new data.

## Solution 2

If your data is just a list of companies, and you only want to run this script once and get your data in a certain range, something like this might work.

```
def get_closing_values(symb):
    comp_info = yf.download(symb, start='2020-5-12', end='2020-5-21')
    s = comp_info['Close']
    s.name = symb
    return s.to_frame().T

companies = ['XOM', 'GE', 'MSFT', 'BP', 'C', 'PG']

df = pd.concat([get_closing_values(comp) for comp in companies])

print(df)

Date  2020-05-11  2020-05-12  2020-05-13  2020-05-14  2020-05-15  2020-05-18   
XOM    45.740002   44.119999   41.930000   42.299999   42.000000   45.340000   
GE      6.190000    6.000000    5.790000    5.700000    5.490000    6.270000   
MSFT  186.740005  182.509995  179.750000  180.529999  183.160004  184.910004   
BP     23.500000   23.059999   22.230000   22.139999   21.820000   23.510000   
C      44.070000   42.349998   40.599998   42.060001   41.919998   45.669998   
PG    115.309998  114.550003  113.919998  113.809998  114.610001  116.209999
```